# Is there a standard for informing users about SSL/HTTPS on Android/iOS?

Tags: android, ios, security

On a standard web browser it's very easy to see how your data is being transferred to servers via the padlock icon and tools like Firebug or Chrome dev can give you the information for things like AJAX requests.

With phone/tablet apps, it's a different matter and is pretty difficult to find out if your data is being transmitted across secure connections or not without digging into network activity.

I was wondering if there are any standards built-in to dev kits about displaying this information on apps as there are in browsers? Something official that can be relied on as opposed to custom icons on individual apps that don't really mean anything. Or do users simply not care that much about this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: NO

Long answer: the user has no way of knowing this across their many many apps. some are of course more secure than others. It can only be hoped that every app sending username and password (let alone more private data) is using best practices.

The nearest thing to this is to get some sort of certificate for your app. I know Symantec offers security certification for your app starting at around $500 U.S. https://www.symantec.com/code-signing/android now this is a code-signing. which is very different but it's the nearest thing unless you apply for a security audit and cert with each release of your app.